# How constructor dependency injection works in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I am using Laravel. I knew we can write constructor dependency injection as below code. I am wondering how it is working? **I mean how constructor get $post and $user model objects?  How it is injected?**

```
    /**
     * Inject the models.
     * @param Post $post
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function __construct(Post $post, User $user)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->post = $post;
        $this->user = $user;
    }
```

Please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: because `__construct(Post $post` ,  `$post` is type of `Post` then create a Post object and assign to `$post`

Comment: How it will find Post class and create it's object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Laravel IoC uses a process called **Autowiring**. This is something that is very common in other languages and other PHP IoC containers.

The idea is to look at the constructor parameters using PHP's [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). Using that, Laravel can see that `$post` needs to be a `Post` instance and thus it will create it on the fly. In short, Laravel will do something like this:

```
$post = new Post();
$user = new User();
$obj = new TheClass($post, $user);
```

(if you wonder how it will find the `Post` class: the Composer autoloader will autoload it based on your configuration in `composer.json`)

This process works well with **Services** (i.e. "utility" classes like the Database, Logger, etc.) but it doesn't work with **Model** classes.

The reason for this is simple: Laravel can't know **which** post and user you want to inject (assuming there are several in your database). Instead you should fetch those instances from the database and pass them around yourself.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu to explain me. :)